# My Jquery code for changing the alt tags on images is not working for IE 7 or IE 8 and works for FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery

```
$j("img").each(function() {
    var img = $j(this);
    var source = img.prop("src");
    var alt = img.prop("alt");
    var source1 = source.substring(source.lastIndexOf('.'), source.lastIndexOf('/'))      
    var source2 = source1.substring(1);                                                   

    if (alt || alt == "") {                                                     
        img.prop("alt", source2);
    }
    else if (alt != source) {                                                     
        img.prop("alt", source2);
    }
 });
```

/* To change alt tag image names to image names within the webpage */

Comment: Sometimes it works with IE 7 and IE 8 when the page is cleared of cache.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation:

> selectedIndex, tagName, nodeName, nodeType, ownerDocument, defaultChecked, and defaultSelected should be retrieved and set with the .prop() method.

The values you're trying to change are attributes, so you should be using the .attr method instead.

```
var alt = img.attr("alt");
var source = img.attr("src");
img.attr("alt", source2);
```

Comment: prop() loads faster then attr() though, because prop reads off the DOM property. Same results with attr() as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the images have URLs like http://cefn.com/blog/photos/blind_mans_buff_credit_velvet_android_240_high.jpg then I fail to see how the lastIndexOf('.') can be before the lastIndexOf('/') which seems to be assumed by your code. You may find different browsers respond to this error differently.

Comment: It doesn't pop up as an error in IE though. It sometimes works and then other times it doesn't work.

Comment: I looked into it and it seems to fail around the prop method, as if IE doesn't read it.